# Historical Chinese Coal Plants Data

Tags: data-request, energy, china

I'm looking for open data on the locations and duration of Chinese coal power plants from 1950 - present. The data would have the completion data of the power plant, latitude, longitude, and (if applicable) when the plant was shut down.

Any ideas where such data might exist?

Answer (score 3):

There is literally a Wikipedia section called

**[List of power stations in China - Coal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_power_stations_in_China#Coal)**

Although the list of 52 is incomplete, it includes the fields that you are searching for

- Station
- Chinese Name
- Province
- Total Capacity (MW)
- Units and Status
- Operator(s)
- Coordinates (latitude and longitude)

The bigger of the plants will have their own Wikipedia pages ([for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guodian_Beilun_Power_Station)), the smaller ones will probably require reading or translating company pages.